# What kind of flower from the Yucatan Peninsula is this?

Tags: identification

Photo taken in the Yucatan peninsula in Mexico (March 2019)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is one of the double-flowered varieties of a Hibiscus. They come in many colors.

Example: https://pixabay.com/photos/hibiscus-double-pink-rosa-sinensis-182421/